# Possible to un-do a push with Git?

Tags: git, github

So I'm currently learning rails and I decided it was a good idea to push my files to git, I missed a step and set myself back a version, I lost about 4 hours work in the blink of an eye, is there any way to undo it? I was in `git co filling-in-layouts` doing all my work, I then `co master` and pushed without merging, now `filling-in-layouts` has nothing in `git status`, and `master` has nothing in `git status`. Really depressed about this, anybody have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously, the solution is to pull!

Comment: In seriousness: did you do any commits before you changed branches? If not, then you really are hosed. Usually, though, git won't let you change branches if the changes you've made are incompatible with the new branch. Nor will the changes silently disappear. Are you sure you didn't commit the changes into one of the two branches before pushing? Double-check your commit history for those changes.

Comment: I'm new to git, I'm learning it along side this tutorial for Rails, I don't know what `pull` does, but I'm assuming it probably retrieves from the server, the only problem is, my repo doesn't have the updated files either... I somehow overwrote everything

Comment: I think you should have used a `git stash` before saying `git checkout master`.

You can recall that saved state using `git stash pop` or something.

Comment: @GeT_Lurk3d: sorry, it was a bad joke. Read my other comment, though.

Comment: @siride is of course correct about it not dropping your modifications silently.  It would give you a warning message if you hadn't committed your changes and were trying to switch branches.

Comment: @siride I don't know what happened, but the files made their way back to me some how... God damnit that was scary, I'll be more careful

Comment: @GeT_Lurk3d: I want you to use `git log -p` to see your commit history. I'll be you committed the changed files accidentally with another commit in either your master or your filling-in-layouts branch.

Comment: try running git `log -p --all --date-order` and see if the output calms you.